# validation username by html onblur in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a signup page in Codeigniter. I want to check the username exists or not exists, when they type it and exit from its input object (onblur event).
It mean I want to check if the username exists or not when users type it and also when losing focus on the input field? 
How I can check it?
I share part of my codes at bellow:
My model (its return True or False):

```
public function Check_UserName_Validate(){
    $CMD = "call UserName_Validate($this->input->post('edtUserName'));";
    $query = $this->db->query($CMD);
    if (mysqli_more_results($this->db->conn_id))
        mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id);
    return $query->row();
}
```

My View:

```
<div>
    First Name : <input type="text" id="edtFirstName" class="MyInputs">
    <br>
    Last Name : <input type="text" id="edtLastName" class="MyInputs">
    <br>
    Username : <input type="text" id="edtUserName" class="MyInputs">
    <br>
    Password : <input type="password" id="edtPassword" class="MyInputs">
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
public function Signup($Flag = 0){
...
    $data["ErrorMSG"] = "";
    $data["ErrorKind"] = 0; 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("edtFirstName", $data["FirstName_Caption"], "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("edtLastName", $data["LastName_Caption"], "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("edtUserName", $data["Username_Caption"], "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("edtPassword", $data["Password_Caption"], "trim|required");
    if ($Flag == 1){
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data["ErrorMSG"] = validation_errors();
            $data["ErrorKind"] = 4; 
            $this->load->view("Signup", $data);
        }
        else{
            /* Insert user information to database */
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view("Signup", $data);
    }
}
```

Please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Check username of the users? You mean you want to check if the username exists or not when users type it and also when losing focus on the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an AJAX function checking on the `edtUserName` field changes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $username_field = $('#edtUserName');

    $username_field.on('keyup', function(){
        check_username($(this).val());
    });

    $username_field.on('blur', function(){
        check_username($(this).val());
    });

});

function check_username(value)
{
    $.post('site/username_exits', {edtUserName : value}, function(response) {
        if (response.exists) {
            // perform what is necessary when the username exists
        }
    }, "json");
}
```

In your controller, you would add:

```
public function username_exits()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
    {
        // load model first
        $this->load->model(<MODEL-NAME>);
        $exists = $this-><MODEL-NAME>->Check_UserName_Validate($this->input->post('edtUserName'));
        echo json_encode(array('exists' => $exists));
    }
    else 
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

Then you should change a little thing in your model function. Remove `$this->input->post` from it and pass the username as a parameter. This way you'll leave the job of collecting data to the controller.

```
public function Check_UserName_Validate($username){
    $CMD = "call UserName_Validate(?);";
    $query = $this->db->query($CMD, $username);

    if (mysqli_more_results($this->db->conn_id))
        mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id);

    return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For check duplicate result you can use simple form_validation **is_unique** method like that -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

where **is_unique** is a method and **users** is a table name and **email** is column name in database table, using that you can check uniqueness.

[Form Validation | CodeIgniter 3.1.7 documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)